# when should be new CU for sharepoint 2013 install after they release?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, cumulative-update

can be June 2015 CU for SharePoint 2013 should be install now for sharepoint 2013 Production servers?
or its better to go with may 2015 CU.

now i am preparing a share point farm for production ,

Comment: Nobody can answer this but you. Is there anything in it that will be of use to you? Have you tested it with your current solution? Does your company  have a policy for applying updates? If not maybe you should implement one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general answer on how to deploy cumulative updates to SharePoint. Generally i install updates only if they are older than 1 or 2 months.

But: Until the May 2015 CU i only installed the September 2014 CU and no newer one (even on new farms!). That is because Microsoft messed things up in every CumulativeUpdate from then.

The ultimate Resource for CUs is maintained by [ToddKlindt](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346). You can find every CU with version number, release date and all known bugs&regressions. I recommend you to read every update carefully and follow the links to see if you would be affected from a specific problem. Then you can decide which update you want to install.

My **today's** blanket recommendation: Install from SP1 media and apply May 2015 CU.